# How can I run a Rails app in production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to start Rails App in production mode? Can any one give me clear explanation

I tried `rails server -e production` but it gives me error in log file saying

```
Mysql2::Error Access denied for user ''@'localhost'
```

Comment: Do you have a valid production section in `config/database.yml`? It looks like you're connecting to your MySQL database without a username.

Comment: the username in prouction is my app name

Answer (score 3):

The command you run is perfectly fine.

It's your configuration files (`config/database.yml`) that are missing the correct settings for the production environment though.

Answer (score 2):

Try `RAILS_ENV=production rails s`

Comment: This is exactly the same as passing `-e` to `rails server`. see `rails server --help`.

Answer (score 1):

To start server in production mode type :

```
RAILS_ENV=production rails s
```

in the console.

Here is my output for this:

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 4.1.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>> Thin web server (v1.5.1 codename Straight Razor)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:3000, CTRL+C to stop
```

as you can see in the second line it is in production.

Be aware that RAILS_ENV is case sensitive.

Seems like you are getting error because your credentials are incorrect, not because your RAILS_ENV is production...

Several things can cause this behaviour.

1. Double check if you created your database for production ENV.
2. Check credentials you use for connection on database.
3. Your mySQL server is not running.

Comment: the error i got is Mysql2::Error Access denied for user ''@'localhost'

Comment: Updated answer, please advise

Comment: *Your mySQL server is not running.* This is not the problem; you don't get a permission denied error, but a connection failed error.

Comment: production:
  <<: *default
  database: appname_production
  username: appname
This is what i wrote in production section of database.yml file

Comment: looks like your username is not getting populated correctly, can you try with hardcoded value, for instance "Test"?